# Twitter Bootstrap Modal not working in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am still fairly new `Rails` and to `twitter bootstrap`. I am working on a modal, but I receive a **"NoMethodError - undefined method 'render.'"**

When I remove the `("<%= escape_javascript(render 'project/new_release') %>"` code from `my_release.js.erb` page, it fades but no window appears.

Also with the error, which won't even allow my project to load from the initial index page, it references my `views/layouts/application.html.erb` line #6 which is my `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`

So I am assuming my .js is all out of whack

I have been working off the the example I saw on the following page- https://coderwall.com/p/ej0mhg

I am trying to add this modal example to an existing project of mine.

Here are some snippets of my code for reference:

Gem File:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.1'
....
....
group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
end
....
....
```

Application.js

```
....
//= require bootstrap-modal
//= require bootstrap
....
```

Routes.rb

```
get "project/new_release" => 'project#new_release', :as => :new_release
```

controller.rb

```
def new_release

respond_to do |format|

  format.html

  format.js

end

end
```

project/index.html.erb

```
<div id="modal-window" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog"
aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>

<%= link_to 'Add release', new_release_path, {:remote => true,
'data-toggle'=> "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'}  %>
```

project/_new_release.html.erb

```
<div class="modal-header">

<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>

<h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>

</div>

<div class="modal-body">

**here comes whatever you want to show!**

</div>

<div class="modal-footer">

<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
```

new_release.js.erb

```
$("#modal-window").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'project/new_release') %>");
```

**EDIT COMMENT**
So still no Pop-up window....It fades then nothing. Does this have to do with the `class="modal hide fade"`?

Comment: can you post your full error and logs?

Comment: Also your new_release.js.erb file is in assets directory or view? You can not access render from assets directory

Comment: why are you adding modals content by ajax? It's a modal so it will be hidden and also it's difficult to debug here. It'll be better if you ask a separate question with relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read that article and it says

`Now we need some javascript to make this works, make a file named same way as the controller action but with the suffix .js.erb for this example should be:`

*Writer mentioned about name of file but forgot to tell you about the path of js file. Your js files path would be **views/controller_name/new_release.js.erb** and not assets/javascript/new_release.js.erb*

If you look at your controller method

```
def new_release
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html  #If it's a html request this line tell rails to look for new_release.html.erb in your views directory
    format.js #If it's a js request this line tell rails to look for new_release.js.erb in your views directory
  end
end
```

For details checkout [**`Working with Javascript in Rails`**](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

Comment: Ahh, okay that makes more sense. I thought the rendering should happen from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Change view file name from "_new_release.html.erb" to "new_release.html.erb" . I dont know why you are using underscore before file name .

if it is partial than use :
    ("<%= escape_javascript(render (partial:=>'project/new_release')) %>"

Comment: this is how [`rails partial`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) are named

Comment: There's a **syntax error** in your render it should be `render partial: 'project/new_release'` or `render :partial=> 'project/new_release'`. Also `render 'project/new_release'`(which is used by @twdeveloper) is just a less verbose way rendering a partial

Comment: @Mandeep So my project has no errors now. However when I click on the link for the Pop-Up Window, it fades then nothing. I do see a line appear on the page almost like the start of form. I have tried removed `hide` from the class, realized I had both `Bootstrap` and `Bootstrap-Modal` in my `Application.js`, so removed `Modal`, still no luck. Even added `modal-dialog` and `modal-content` to my div classes`. Any suggestions/ideas?