# Twitter Bootstrap Modal not displaying window in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

When I click on the link for my Modal Pop-Up Window, it fades then nothing. I do see a line appear on the page almost like the start of form. I have tried many suggestions, to remove `hide` from the `class`, realized I had both `Bootstrap` and `Bootstrap-Modal` in my `application.js`, so removed `Modal`, still no luck.  Any suggestions/ideas?

My code is in the previous question, which is below. I did move my `new_release.js.erb` into my view/"controller_name" instead of `assests/javascripts`, like it was suggested.

[Bootstrap Modal(previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939320/twitter-bootstrap-modal-not-working-in-rails))

**EDITED CODE**

Application.js

```
//= require bootstrap
```

Routes.rb

```
get "project/new_release" => 'project#new_release', :as => :new_release
```

controller.rb

```
def new_release
respond_to do |format|
format.html
format.js
end
end
```

project/index.html.erb

```
<div id="modal-window" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog"
aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>

<%= link_to 'Add release', new_release_path, remote: true %>
```

project/_new_release.html.erb

```
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
</div>

<div class="modal-body" style="height:540px; max-height:540px; 
width:630px; max-width:630px;">
Test Modal
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
```

views/project/new_release.js.erb

```
$("#modal-window").html("<%=j render 'project/new_release' %>");
$('#modal-window').modal('show'); // this will show up your modal once it has its data
```

**development.log**

```
Started GET "/project/new_release" for 123.4.5.6. at Date/Time

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action'show' could not be found  
for ProjectController):
....
.... 
(50 lines of actionpack (3.2.13) process, calls, dispatch. journey call, rake call. 
C:/RailsIntaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb)

Rendered C:/RailsIntaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/
actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/
rescues/unknown_action.erb within rescue/layout
```

Comment: why are you adding modals content by ajax? It's a modal so it should be hidden by default and then only clicking that link you can simply show that modal

Comment: I was going off of the Demo that I found on `Twitter Bootstrap Modals` and trying to get it to work from there. Like I mentioned fairly new to all of this. For now just trying to get the Modal window to even display using the Twitter Bootstrap way.

Comment: `<%= link_to 'Add release', new_release_path,
'data-toggle'=> "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'  %>` should open up your modal

Comment: I just edited my `link_to` with your suggestion. Still the same fade screen but no window display. A line forms on the screen though like it wants to generate a window.  Here is the code I previously had for my `link`.  `<%= link_to 'Add release', new_release_path, {:remote => true,'data-toggle'=> "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'}  %>`

Answer (score 0):

Just checked your code again there are couple of issues

Your modal code

```
<div id="modal-window" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

**is an empty div so it won't show up unless you have width and height on it**

Your link

```
<%= link_to 'Add release', new_release_path, {:remote => true, 'data-toggle'=> "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'}  %>
```

This will *call up js to show your modal which is empty and then add content inside your modal which must be messing it up*

**Fix**

**Without ajax**

Your modal should look like:

```
<div id="modal-window" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    **here comes whatever you want to show!**
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your link

```
<%= link_to 'Add release', new_release_path, 'data-toggle'=> "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'  %>
```

**With Ajax:**

Your modal:

```
<div id="modal-window" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

Your link

```
<%= link_to 'Add release', new_release_path, remote: true %>
```

Your js.erb file

```
$("#modal-window").html("<%=j render 'project/new_release' %>");
$('#modal-window').modal('show'); // this will show up your modal once it has its data
```

Comment: Okay, I will apply these updates. See how this comes out. Truly appreciate the advice.

Comment: Okay....Still can't get the dang thing to work. When I tried the "without Ajax" way, nothing happens. When I tried the "With Ajax" way and clicked on the `Add release button` nothing happens and it says `AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action'show' could not be found for ProjectController)

Comment: I have posted my edited code. These include the changes you suggested for "**With Ajax:**

Comment: I added info, above, from the development.log

Comment: @Twdeveloper which gem are you using for bootstrap? i think it's not able to find js to show it

Comment: `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.1'`

Comment: `group :assests do gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'`

Comment: @Twdeveloper Ah that js call was for bootstrap3. If you can then you should update your bootstrap with https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Answer (score 0):

What actually fixed it for me was changing the `div` class from `modal hide fade` to just `modal`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of issue, with a bootstrap modal window not showing up.
I solved the issue by changing `class="modal hide fade"`  to `class="modal fade"`.

There is a tutorial on this (https://coderwall.com/p/ej0mhg/open-a-rails-form-with-twitter-bootstrap-modals). It's quite concise and works perfectly, only with the modification I mentioned above.